# Can i install docker on ubuntu trusty

Tags: docker, ubuntu-14.04

I want to install docker on my machine which runs ubuntu-14.04 Trusty.
But in the official documentation it dosent say anything about ubuntu 14 Only about ubuntu 19, 18, 16

Answer (score 0):

You can install the docker on ubuntu 14.04 with the guide given below.

https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/how-to-install-docker-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts/